# Variables don't work

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help with JavaScript. I want to have an "a" link with changeble text. But there is a problem with variables, they don't as they must. There is only ("Successfully check = false") statement in console, never ("Successfully check = true").
There is a code:

changeText.js

```
    function check1() {
      document.getElementById("ck").innerHTML = "Включить переливание фона 
    кликабельно";
      return false;
    }

    function check2() {
      document.getElementById("ck").innerHTML = "Отключить переливание фона 
    кликабельно";
      return false;
    }

    function changeText() {
      var check = true;
      if (check = true) {
        check1();
        check == false;
        console.log("Successfully check = false");
      }
      else {
        check2();
        check == true;
        console.log("Successfully check = true");
      }
    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Пианинка</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="ck" onclick="changeText()">Отключить переливание фона (кликабельно)</a>
<script src="changeText.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the condition you should use `==` to test equality. `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: A single `=` is an assignment, a double `==` is a comparison.

Comment: You are also creating and setting `check` immediately to `true` in your function so it's always going to test as true. Variables created inside a function do not retain state between function calls.

Comment: @PatrickEvans it is just necessary to make it true at first and on every click to change the text of link.

Comment: Then maybe move that assignment out of the function.

Comment: Please see my answer, it should help you :)

Comment: The functions named `check1()` and `check2()` don't actually check anything. They just `return false;` no matter what the data is. And you never use the return value when you call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is the same as saying `SET THIS TO THIS` `=` does not mean `EQUAL TO`. `==` and `===` do, but not `=`.

So change your code to this:

```
function check1() {
      document.getElementById("ck").innerHTML = "Включить переливание фона 
    кликабельно";
      return false;
    }

    function check2() {
      document.getElementById("ck").innerHTML = "Отключить переливание фона 
    кликабельно";
      return false;
    }

    function changeText() {
      var check = true;
      if (check == true) {
        check1();
        check = false;
        console.log("Successfully check = false");
      }
      else {
        check2();
        check = true;
        console.log("Successfully check = true");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Oh thanks! It is just hard to me to understand everything because I learn JavaScript for a week. Thanks for information again!

Answer (score 0):

Well the `if` statement is wrong, you should have an `==`, but before you do `var check = true` which will always lead to check be `true`.

Note: if you want to evaluate a variable to `true`, you can simply type `if (check){}`

Comment: There are more problems than this.